# Android - how to set alarm X days before specific date

Tags: android, calendar, notifications, alarmmanager

I have seen a lot of tutorials for creating an AlarmManager and bringing up a notification at a specific date, but I was wondering how to do it for X days before.

For example, if I have an event on January 8th, 2014 and I want to set it a week before to Jan 1st, 2014, I would just set the alarm as this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Day-7);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

However what if the event was on January 4th, 2014, then I would want to set the date to December 28th, 2013. Is there a function that can do this? Or do I have to write a lot of cases?

Comment: the difference b/w today and X days , convert the difference into the milisecond and add the value into the calendar.getTimeInMillis()+ difference_days_into_milisecond

Comment: 1 - WHY?? 2 - You can't: If the current time is after the alarm time, the alarm will fire IMMEDIATELY.

Comment: 1 - Because I want to get a notification of a task before its specific due date.

2 - Also, this was a hypothetical date. Not a real date. I was giving an example.

Answer (score 3):

the event was on January 4th, 2014:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long eventTime=calendar.getTimeInMillis();//Returns Time in milliseconds

long oneDay=AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;//Converts 24 Hrs(1 Day) to milliseconds
int noOfDays=4
long reminderTime=eventTime-(noOfDays*oneDay);//Time in milliseconds when the alarm will shoot up & you do not need to concider month/year with this approach as time is already in milliseconds.

//Set alarm
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminderTime, pendingIntent);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

get your current time in milliseconds and subtract the no. of days from it,here 1 day= 24*60*60*1000 = 86400000

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(no. of days * 86400000)), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hope this helps you,if there are any queries related to this be comfortable to ask.All the best :)

Comment: Why (calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(no. of days * 86400000)) minus ? this will give you the previous time from the current date ???

Comment: I meant that get the time in millis of the event date and then minus the days.eg if you have event on  January 8th, 2014 and you want a notification alarm before 7 days then get the time in millis for 8 jan 2014 and subtract 7*86400000